# Handle File.write insufficient disk space

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing an application for both Android and iOS. In this application, I download images from the remote server which the user can view them. Now, my question is that when we develop native applications, if the storage space is insufficient, then during file write, it will throw an exception.

Now, similarly when we are doing the same in Appcelerator, file.write(blob), if the disk is not sufficient, will the call throw can exception, or do we need to check for the return value to confirm that it has been written properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soumy, you will need to check the return value.

If you looked in the SDK source code you will see that the *native* exception for both Android/iOS is send as a *false* value, through the Kroll Proxy.

You can check [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/3aa452bc8ce48a0ed4e297573fd0b7a60e145921/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/TiFileProxy.java#L274) for the *File.write* implementation on JAVA and 
 [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/bc8b355feb14741c06c124eff49ec13c503965af/iphone/Classes/TiFilesystemFileProxy.m#L378) for the *File.write* implementation on Obj-C

Comment: Perfect. I was looking for the native framework implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is the method `spaceAvailable` inside Ti.Filesyste.File (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-spaceAvailable). You could use that the create a manual check before saving the file if you know how big it is

Comment: Yes, we can use the API, but my question is that whether can we know if the file write on insufficient storage would generate an exception or not.